# div manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this

```
<div class="out"> 
out asdaasd
<div class="in"> in </div>
out
</div>
```

and want to get it to this

```
<div class="out"> out asdaasd <div>
<div class="in"> in </div>
<div class="out"> out </div>
```

with arbitary text inside out, how can I detect position of inner div and get what I need?

Comment: Would you be fine with wrapping this entire thing in a div with an id?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. This question is extremely vague.

Comment: @Matt how specific can it get than the given input and output in the question?

Comment: There's no context. It just says "turn A into B". Without context, you get sloppy, generalized solutions.

Comment: How does a poorly written question get so many up-votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var outers = document.getElementsByClassName("out");

[].forEach.call(outers, function(outer) {
    var inner = outer.getElementsByClassName("in")[0];
    var children = outer.childNodes;

    var flag = true;
    var before = document.createElement("div");
    var after = document.createElement("div");
    before.classList.add("out");
    after.classList.add("out");

    [].slice.call(children).forEach(function(node) {
        if (node == inner) {
            return flag = false;
        }
        if (flag) {
            before.appendChild(node);
        } else {
            after.appendChild(node);
        }
    });
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    frag.appendChild(before);
    frag.appendChild(inner);
    frag.appendChild(after);
    outer.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, outer);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zXRtV/17/)

Answer (score 0):

This will create the desired structure into a new div.

```
<div class="out"> 
out asdaasd
<div class="in"> in </div>
out
</div>

<div id="xyz">
</div>

$('.out').contents().each(function() {        
    if(this.nodeType == 3) {
        $('#xyz').append("<div class='out'>"+$(this).text()+"</div>");
    }
    else {
        $('#xyz').append(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: You broke the text nodes when you used jQuery

Comment: what do you mean? I can get text nodes and their values just fine with this code.

Comment: I don't get it. When I do contents().each(), I get 3 elements - 1. text node (out asdaasd) 2- div with id 'in' 3- text node (out) ... so what's merging the multiple text nodes and hacking the DOM and dirty html strings?

Comment: your right, I didn't read it quite right. I still wouldn't trust `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('<div class="out"> out asdaasd<div class="in"> in </div>out</div>'),
  tmp = $("<div/>");

a.contents().each(function() {
if(this.nodeType == 1)
  tmp.append(this);
else
  tmp.append($(this).wrap("<div class='out' />").parent());
});
tmp.html()
```

Comment: That will wrap every text node in it's own div creating more then 2 `.out` div's